# Gibbs distribution as a pushfoward

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics

Let $\Omega_{0}:=\{-1,1\}$ be a single spin space. If $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is a fixed finite set, take $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra $2^{\Omega_{0}}$ on $\Omega_{0}$. We define $\Omega_{\Lambda} :=\{-1,1\}^{\Lambda}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda}$ to be the associate product $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda} = 2^{\Omega_{\Lambda}}$. Moreover, take $\Omega:= \Omega_{0}^{\mathbb{Z}^{d}}$ and $\mathcal{F} := 2^{\Omega}$. If $\eta \in \Omega$, we can define the Hamiltonian for ferromagnetic models $\mathcal{H}_{\Lambda,h, \eta}:\Omega_{\Lambda}\to \mathbb{R}$ to be:
$$H_{\Lambda,h,\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda}) := -\sum_{x,y \in \Lambda}J(x,y)\omega_{x}\omega_{y}-\sum_{x\in \Lambda}\bigg{(}h+\sum_{y\in \Lambda^{c}}J(x,y)\eta_{y}\bigg{)}\omega_{x} $$
Here, $J=J(x,y)$ are coupling strenghts which are assumed to be non-negative and translation invariant. The above defined Hamiltonian is often referred as the Hamiltonian with boundary condition $\eta$.

Suppose $\nu_{0}$ is a counting measure on $\Omega_{0}$ given by $\nu_{0}(\emptyset)=0$, $\nu_{0}(\{\pm 1\}) = 1/2$. Take $\nu_{\Lambda}$ to be its associate product measure. The finite volume Gibbs state $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta, h, \eta}$ is a probability measure on $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ defined to be:
$$\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h,\eta}(A) := \frac{1}{Z_{\Lambda, \beta, h, \eta}}\int_{A}e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda,h,\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda})}d\nu_{\Lambda}(\omega_{\Lambda})$$
where $\beta > 0$ is the inverse absolute temperature and $Z_{\Lambda,\beta,h,\eta}$ is a normalization constant called the partition function.

Now, as discussed in [Friedli & Velenik's book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html) (see chapter 3, page 81) it is convenient to extend some of the above definitions to subspaces of $\Omega$. Thus, let $\Omega_{\Lambda}^{\eta}:=\{\omega \in \Omega: \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{$\omega_{x}=\eta_{x}$ if $x \in \Lambda^{c}$}\}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda}^{\eta}$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda}^{\eta} = 2^{\Omega_{\Lambda}^{\eta}}$ on it. We define the Gibbs state $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta, h}^{\eta}$ on $\Omega_{\Lambda}^{\eta}$ by its evaluation on singletons:
$$\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h}^{\eta}(\{\omega\}) = \frac{1}{Z_{\Lambda,\beta,h}^{\eta}}e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda,h}^{\eta}(\omega)}$$
where, here $H_{\Lambda, h}^{\eta}(\omega) := H_{\Lambda,h,\eta}(\Omega_{\Lambda})$ with $\omega_{\Lambda}$ being the projection of $\omega$ to $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ and $Z_{\Lambda,\beta,h}^{\eta}$ the new normalizing constant.

Question: Is $\mu_{\Lambda, \beta,h}^{\eta}$ just the pushfoward of $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h,\eta}$? In other words, consider the injection $i_{\eta}: \Omega_{\Lambda}\to \Omega_{\Lambda}^{\eta}$ given by $i_{\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda}) = \omega_{\Lambda}|\eta_{\Lambda^{c}}$ where $\omega_{\Lambda}|\eta_{\Lambda^{c}}$ is the sequence $\sigma$ on $\Omega$ with $\sigma_{x}=\omega_{x}$ if $x\in \Lambda$ and $\sigma_{x} = \eta_{x}$ otherwise. Is it true that $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h}^{\eta}(A) = \mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h,\eta}(i_{\eta}^{-1}(A))$? See, I think this is true because it seems these two measures coincide on singletons, but I might be misunderstanding something.

**ADD:** I think I should elaborate my question a little more. If these two measures agree on singletons, they surely will agree on all $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ since this set is finite. The point is that I don't know for sure if these measures indeed agree on singletons. But let me elaborate the reasoning that led me to this belief.

Because $\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda}=2^{\Omega}$, every singleton is measurable. Thus, take a singleton $\{\omega_{\Lambda}\} \in \mathcal{F}_{\Lambda}$. Then, because $\nu_{\Lambda}$ is a counting measure, we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu_{\Lambda, \beta, h,\eta}(i_{\eta}^{-1}(\{\omega\})) = \mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h\eta}(\{\omega_{\Lambda}\}) =  \frac{1}{Z_{\Lambda,\beta,h,\eta}}e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda, h,\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda})} = \frac{e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda, h,\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda})}}{\sum_{\omega_{\Lambda}\in \Omega_{\Lambda}}e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda, h,\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda})}} = \frac{e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda, h}^{\eta}(\omega_{\Lambda})}}{\sum_{\omega \in \Omega_{\Lambda}^{\eta}}e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda,h}^{\eta}(\omega)}} = \mu_{\Lambda,\beta,h}^{\eta}(\{\omega\})
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If two measures on a finite set agree on singletons, doesn’t that mean they’re equal?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas it surely does. Maybe my post was not entirely clear on this. The point is that I think but I don't know for sure that these measures agree on singletons. Maybe I should edit it explaining the reasoning behind this belief.

Comment: Yes, these two measures indeed agree on singletons. Which point of view is more convenient depends on the application (for instance, in Chapter 6 of our book, the second point of view is better suited for the analysis; in Chapter 8, the first point of view turns out to be more convenient; in Chapter 3, both could be used equally easily). As you notice, it is very simple to go from one to the other.

Comment: @YvanVelenik great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MathMath:  On $\Omega=\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$, taking $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$ as the sigma-algebra is no good. In general, your sigma-algebras should be Borel sigma-algebras for suitable topologies. For finite sets like $\Omega_0$ or $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ the correct topology is the discrete one. But when considering $\Omega$, you should take the product topology coming from the discrete one on the factors $\{-1,1\}$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ should be the Borel sigma-algebra for this product topology.

Comment: The whole point of the construction, is to consider the limit of probability measures when $\Lambda$ fills the whole lattice. This is a problem of weak convergence of probability measures, which requires topologies for this to make sense.